# Expl3 prop doesn't seem to work when the key is a macro value

Tags: expansion, expl3, l3prop

I'd expect this example code to give two identical lines, however `\usevalue{\xyz}` doesn't result in `XYZ` as the other. Can I force the key to be expanded to make `\usevalue{\xyz}` and `\usevalue{0}` refer to the same value?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_my_data_prop
\cs_new_protected:Npn \addvalue #1#2 { \prop_gput:Nnn \g_my_data_prop {#1} {#2} }
\cs_new:Npn \usevalue #1 { \prop_get:Nn \g_my_data_prop {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\edef\xyz{0}

\addvalue{0}{XYZ}

Value: \usevalue{0}

Value: \usevalue{\xyz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to expand the macro first:

```
\expandafter\usevalue\expandafter{\xyz}
```

You could define `\usevalue` in a way that it expands its argument once (equivalent to the line above) per default:

```
\cs_new:Npn \usevalue #1 { \prop_get:No \g_my_data_prop {#1} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_get:Nn { No }
```

If you want a bit more flexibility and decide on a per case basis you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_kazi_data_prop

\cs_new_protected:Npn \kazi_addvalue:nn #1#2 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_kazi_data_prop {#1} {#2}
}

\cs_new:Npn \kazi_usevalue:n #1 {
  \prop_get:Nn \g_kazi_data_prop {#1}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \kazi_usevalue:n { o }

\NewDocumentCommand \addvalue { mm }
  { \kazi_addvalue:nn {#1} {#2} }

\NewDocumentCommand \usevalue { sm }
  {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      { \kazi_usevalue:o {#2} }
      { \kazi_usevalue:n {#2} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\xyz{0}

\addvalue{0}{XYZ}

Value: \usevalue{0}

Value: \usevalue*{\xyz}

\end{document}
```

This way `\usevalue` is not expandable any more, though, which may not be wanted.  If you need it to be expandable use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`. (Also the arguments aren't `\long` any more.  Use `+m` in the argument spec if you need them to be long.)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I might change the names though... :)